# Error in fit_transform while finding tf-idf in Python

Tags: python, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
mylist = [
    'a a b c',
    'a c c c d e f',
    'a c d d d',
    'a d f',
]
df = pd.DataFrame({"texts": mylist})
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=[1, 1])
tfidf_separate = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df["texts"])
```

I am trying to find tf-idf value for “d” in line 3. But, it is showing me empty vocabulary error "ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words".

Any advice on how to resolve the error would be appreciated!

Comment: Checkout tfidf default paramos, it looks like your vocab is empty, you are be using inappropriate default values. Is exactly this your example or it is just a minimal working example?

Comment: Yes, this is my actual example text. tried with (stopwords = none) but no hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

- define `analyzer='char'` so that TfidfVectorizer works with the letters;
- find the index of `d` in the vocabulary and use it

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
mylist = [
    'a a b c',
    'a c c c d e f',
    'a c d d d',
    'a d f',
]
df = pd.DataFrame({"texts": mylist})
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=[1, 1], analyzer='char')
tfidf_separate = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df["texts"])
ind = tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_['d']
tfidf_separate.todense()[2, ind]
>>> 0.6490674853546846
```